# I have integrated twilio otp api and it suddenly stop working

Tags: twilio, one-time-password

I have integrated twilio and it was working fine but suddenly
end users stop receiving top message at their mobile. Is there any capacity problem if yes then how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Without providing the code, I can give the following suggestions to check upon.

#### 1. Check if the Twilio Account has enough balance to send messages

you can check this in the dashboard.

#### 2. Check if the Message template used is verified or not.

If the template is rejected for some reason, you won't be able to use it.

#### 3. Use the API Gateway Dashboard to determine the cause for no sending messages.

If you can see the messaged being in outbounds mode, but not being sent, you can check the reason for it.

#### 4. Check if the Twilio API library used has changed the API structure

Refer to Twilio Docs and confirm if the APIs have received some changes in them, deprecating any changes. (This is very rare, as most API Providers keep the Legacy API code format active for some time for users to migrate from it.)

#### 5. Confirm If any New Government Rules are changed.

Ex. In India, there are some new laws put up for sending SMSes to users. You would need to follow the rules to register the template again to a Mobile Carrier's site, and then use it. These details will be provided on Twilio Dashboard.